# Setting Editable/NotEditable area with link in JSF?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2, taglib

Hello everyone i am new at JSF-Hibernate. I have a table in my database called "Personels" and I am getting records from there with a function and showing at "ListAllPersonels.xhtml" page. I have a link next to each surname and when click on it the row that clicked should turn to editable area. I have boolean variable for holding value of each records. Everthing is work except editable area link.When click on it, nothing changes. The value of "editable" doesnt turn to "true" from "false". So my codes are here, where is problem? Thanks....

My ManagedBean - PersonelMB;

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PersonelMB implements Serializable{

/**
 * Creates a new instance of PersonelMB
 */
public PersonelMB() {
}
private int personelid;
private String personelname,personelsurname;

public int getPersonelid() {
    return personelid;
}

public void setPersonelid(int personelid) {
    this.personelid = personelid;
}

public String getPersonelname() {
    return personelname;
}

public void setPersonelname(String personelname) {
    this.personelname = personelname;
}

public String getPersonelsurname() {
    return personelsurname;
}

public void setPersonelsurname(String personelsurname) {
    this.personelsurname = personelsurname;
}



private NewHibernateUtil hu;
private Session s;
private Personels personel;
private List<Personels> plist;

public List<Personels> getAllPersonelsFromDatabase(){
    plist=new ArrayList<>();
    s=hu.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    Query qu=s.createQuery("from Personels");
    plist=qu.list();
    s.getTransaction().commit();
    s.close();
    return plist;
}

public String addRecord(){
    Personels p=new Personels();
    p.setPersonelName(personelname);
    p.setPersonelSurname(personelsurname);
    s=hu.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    s.save(p);
    s.getTransaction().commit();
    s.close();
    p=null;
    personelname="";
    personelsurname="";
    return "success";
}

public String editRecord(Personels p){
    p.setEditable(true);
    return null;
}

public String saveAlteration(Personels pr){
    for(Personels pers:mylist)
        pers.setEditable(false);

    s=hu.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    s.update(pr);
    s.getTransaction().commit();
    s.close();
    return null;
}
public String deleteRecord(Personels p){
    s=hu.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    s.delete(p);
    s.getTransaction().commit();
    s.close();
    return "deleted";
}
}
```

My Java Class - Personels.java

```
public class Personels  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer personelId;
 private String personelName;
 private String personelSurname;

public Personels() {
}

public Personels(String personelName, String personelSurname) {
   this.personelName = personelName;
   this.personelSurname = personelSurname;
}

public Integer getPersonelId() {
    return this.personelId;
}

public void setPersonelId(Integer personelİd) {
    this.personelId = personelİd;
}
public String getPersonelName() {
    return this.personelName;
}

public void setPersonelName(String personelName) {
    this.personelName = personelName;
}
public String getPersonelSurname() {
    return this.personelSurname;
}

public void setPersonelSurname(String personelSurname) {
    this.personelSurname = personelSurname;
}

boolean editable;

public boolean isEditable() {
    return editable;
}

public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
    this.editable = editable;
}

}
```

My index.xhtml

```xhtml
<h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <f:facet name="Personel Register Form"/>
            <h:outputLabel value="NAME: "/>
            <h:inputText value="#{personelMB.personelname}"/>

            <h:outputLabel value="SURNAME: "/>
            <h:inputText value="#{personelMB.personelsurname}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Save" type="submit"  action="#{personelMB.addRecord()}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandLink value="List All Personels" action="listallpersonels.xhtml"/>
    </h:form>
```

My listallpersonels.xhtml;

```xhtml
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{personelMB.getAllPersonelsFromDatabase()}" var="p" >
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">NAME</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{p.personelName}" rendered="#{p.editable}" size="15"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{p.personelName}" rendered="#{not p.editable}"/>

        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">SURNAME</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{p.personelSurname}" rendered="#{not p.editable}"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{p.personelSurname}" rendered="#{p.editable}" size="15" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">DELETE</f:facet>
            <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{personelMB.deleteRecord(p)}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">EDIT</f:facet>
            <h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{personelMB.editRecord(p)}" 
                                     rendered="#{not p.editable}"/>

            <h:commandButton value="Save Alteration" action="#{personelMB.saveAlteration(p)}"
                                     rendered="#{p.editable}" />
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Where is it mentioned that you have to compulsorily use a session scoped managed bean for this kind of things in JSF 2.x.x?

Comment: @Tiny 
i saw an example about this and it used session scoped. There was just one difference, i am using hibernate for getting information from database, the example were using list for recording name,surnama. The example did not use connection of database. So what kind of scope should i use you think ?

Comment: A view scoped bean should many a times suffice adequately while performing basic CRUD operations.

Comment: Agreed with @Tiny. It is recommended for you to use View scoped in your scenario. You will most likely will be using Session scope when it comes to have access to LOGIN information throughout the application.

Comment: I supose `personelMB#editRecord` method is not getting hit?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at primefaces, it had some features. And you should find some responses to your questions.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

And then try something like this

```
<p:dataTable value="#{personelMB.getAllPersonelsFromDatabase()}" var="p" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellP">
```

Comment: thanks @DamienBoue , i will study on it but i want to learn how to solve without primefaces. :)

Comment: i don't know how to do what you want but i think that one possibility is to surround your <h:outputText> with a link that have a listener  witch will change your editable value to true and then update your view.